# Intersystems Objectscript, Persisted Class with Non Persisted Property

Tags: intersystems-cache, objectscript

> Can we create non persisted property inside persisted class. Simply do not save the property(column) with %Save()

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for transient property parameter:

```
Property Name As %String [ Transient ];
```

From [docs](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=ROBJ_property_transient):

> Specifies whether the property is stored in the database. Applies only to persistent classes.

Comment: Can you add the ref doc

Comment: Pasted another link, sorry ^^ Now it's fixed.

Comment: @VivekRanjan also check this link http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GOBJ_proplit#GOBJ_proplit_computed